# How to rid of some decimals on my pie chart in R

Tags: r

I've been looking all day for this answer, but with any luck.
I'm newbie and I've been trying to do a Pie chart with ggplot2, but I can't reduce decimals on my pie chart and put everything in order.

```
ggplot(data=wolf_summary, mapping = aes(x= "", y = Percent, fill= Hobby)) +
      geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(cumsum(rev(wolf_summary$Percent)), 1)) +
      coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1) + 
      labs(title= "Wolf Villagers Hobbies") +
      geom_text(aes(label = Percent),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

This is my pie chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma0WJ.png

I wonder if anyone can help me. tysm in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use round function in the label.

```
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Percent, digits = 1),
           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```